# R error when trying to call AICcmodavg package

Tags: r

I'm trying to call the AICcmpdavg package, following the instructions available on this webpage: https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/akaike-information-criterion/.

After installing the package using "install.packages("AICcmodavg")", I try to call the package using the library function.

> library(AICcmodavg)

However, I get the following error message:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘AICcmodavg’ in .doLoadActions(where, attach):
error in load action .**A**.1 for package terra: loadModule(module = "spat", what = TRUE, env = ns, loadNow = TRUE): Unable to load module "spat": function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘PairedData’ was built under R version 4.1.1
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.1.1
3: package ‘AICcmodavg’ was built under R version 4.1.1

This is very similar to something described on the following webpage for another package:https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/363

I tried the following suggestion, but it did not fix my problem:

> withr::with_makevars(c(PKG_LIBS = "-liconv"), install.packages("haven"), assignment = "+=")

Does anybody know what is causing the issue and how I might be able to fix it?

Comment: The problem should go away after you reinstall Rcpp and terra